# AngularJS calling a controller in a directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, controller, directive

I am trying to follow from what I can tell so far is a pretty decent tutorial but I am a little stuck on a part where I need to create a directive to seperate a chunk of html and use a controller to generate the data.

```
var app = angular.module('newModule',[]);

app.directive('stateView', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'state-view.html',
        controller: 'stateController',
        controllerAs: 'stateCtrl'
    }
});


 app.controller('stateController',function(){
     this.addStateTo = function(country){
         if(!country.states){
         country.states = [];
         }
         country.states.push({name: this.newState});
         this.newState = "";
     };
 });
```

My HTML stateview looks like this (C is a value from another controller to itterate through a list of other objects).

```
<div>
    <input type="text" name="state" ng-model="stateCtrl.newState">
    <a href ng-click="stateCtrl.addStateTo(c)"> Add State {{ stateCtrl.newState }}</a>
</div>
```

and the only HTML referrence I have on my index is the following:

```
<state-view></state-view>
```

It looks clean, but the problem is that it does not reconize the function addStateTo unless I tell the DIV element that it is the ng-controller called StateController. Isn't this what the directive is telling the HTML attribute?

Comment: Try adding bindToController: true after controllerAs in your directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the ControllerAs syntax and referencing the controller context appropriately (i.e. stateCtrl.newState and stateCtrl.addStateTo(c)).  The problem is that you aren't creating the controller context properly.  Your controller code should look like this:

```
app.controller('stateController', function() {
  var vm = this;

  this.addStateTo = function(country) {
    if (!country.states) {
      country.states = [];
    }
    country.states.push({
      name: vm.newState
    });
    vm.newState = "";
  };
});
```

Working example [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/sL2vr8ApXvfWbgNpV1nH?p=preview)

Comment: The multiple runs are a result of the angular digest cycle executing more than once.  There is no need to use the ng-controller directive in your HTML since you have already assigned the controller in your directive.  Remove the ng-controller directive.

Comment: I am almost inclined to sent the entire thing, because I dont get why this does not work as soon as I remove the ng-controller reference from the HTML element ><, as if he doesn't understand the scope of the function anymore.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, do you mean that addStateTo() isn't being called or that there is an error when it is called?

Comment: @HemlockDevelopment - I have modified my answer to include a link to a working example

Comment: The function is not being called anymore as soon as I remove the attribute refference from the div tag.

Comment: @HemlockDevelopment - check out the working example in my answer to see how your code might be different than what I have working.

Comment: Thanks for the example! That helped me figure out what the problem was. Apparently I was using a 1.1.5 version where this does not work? When I updated it to 1.5.6. I feel a little coding 101 fool right now :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead (`$scope` instead of `this`):

```
app.controller('stateController',function($scope){
    $scope.addStateTo = function(country){
        if(!country.states){
          country.states = [];
        }
        country.states.push({name: this.newState});
        $scope.newState = "";
    };
});
```

OR

```
app.controller('stateController',function(){
    var vm = this;
    vm.addStateTo = function(country){
        if(!country.states){
          country.states = [];
        }
        country.states.push({name: this.newState});
        vm.newState = "";
    };
});
```

Comment: Sadly it fails to respond as soon as I remove the refference from the DIV tag in my HTM :(

Also shouldn't this.newState also be $scope of vm? I tried but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Don't really understand what you mean. Yes, it should, and it is.

Comment: Well with the $scope use it doesn't want to work at all.
It does work when I use :

<div ng-controller="stateController as stateCtrl">

Answer (score 0):

Try adding bindto controller true in your directive. And also the above answer is correct in fixing other issues you may run into, i.e mapping your this to the function, though at present not doing that may not cause a problem.

```
var app = angular.module('newModule',[]);

app.directive('stateView', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'state-view.html',
        controller: 'stateController',
        controllerAs: 'stateCtrl',
        bindToController: true
    }
});


 app.controller('stateController',function(){
     var vm = this;
     vm.addStateTo = function(country){
         if(!country.states){
         country.states = [];
         }
         country.states.push({name: vm.newState});
         vm.newState = "";
     };
 });
```